# How to iterate over a string applying a condition?

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I'm writing a code that gives each letter of a string a certain number and return the final number when it has run the whole string.

I've tried using elif as well but I didn't get the right result.

```
full_name = str(input('Enter  your full name: '))
full_name.upper()

sum = 0
for i in full_name:
    if 'A' or 'J' or 'S' in full_name:
        sum += 1
        if 'B' or 'K' or 'T' in full_name:
            sum += 2
            if 'C' or 'L' or 'U' in full_name:
                sum +=3
                if 'D' or 'M' or 'V' in full_name:
                    sum +=4
                    if 'E' or 'N' or 'W' in full_name:
                        sum+=5
                        if 'F' or 'O' or 'X' in full_name:
                            sum+=6
                            if 'G' or 'P' or 'Y' in full_name:
                                sum+=7
                                if 'H' or 'Q' or 'Z' in full_name:
                                    sum+=8
                                    if 'I' or 'R'  in full_name:
                                        sum+=9
print(sum)
```

My code is running but I don't get the right number. For example if  `full_name = 'abc'` , running the code I will get `sum = 135`. I should get `sum= 6`

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want better code that solves your problem, or an explanation of why your code does not work, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your not saving your upper translation and your total might be lieing to you. Anyway, I would use a dictionary of values with lookup instead of a chain of if statements like that.

```
full_name = str(input('Enter  your full name: ')).upper()

letters = {"A":1, "J":1, "S":1, "B":2, "K":2, "T":2, "C":3, "L":3, "U":3,
           "D":4, "M":4, "V":4, "E":5, "N":5, "W":5, "F":6, "O":6, "X":6,
           "G":7, "P":7, "Y":7, "H":8, "Q":8, "Z":8, "I":9, "R":9}

total = 0
for i in full_name:
    try:
        total += letters.get(i)
    except TypeError:   #handles items not in dictionary such as space and punct
        pass


print(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
full_name = input('Enter  your full name: ').upper()

Sum = 0
for i in full_name:
    if i == ('A' or 'J' or 'S'):
        Sum += 1
    if i == ('B' or 'K' or 'T'):
        Sum += 2
    if i == ('C' or 'L' or 'U'):
        Sum +=3
    if i == ('D' or 'M' or 'V'):
        Sum +=4
    if i == ('E' or 'N' or 'W'):
        Sum+=5
    if i == ('F' or 'O' or 'X'):
        Sum+=6
    if i == ('G' or 'P' or 'Y'):
        Sum+=7
    if i == ('H' or 'Q' or 'Z'):
        Sum+=8
    if i == ('I' or 'R'):
        Sum+=9
print(Sum)
```

And you can write your code this way:

```
full_name = input('Enter  your full name: ').upper()

t = ''.maketrans('AJSBKTCLUDMVENWFOXGPYHQZIR','11122233344455566677788899')
List = [i.translate(t) for i in full_name]

Sum = 0
for x in List:
    Sum += int(x)

print(Sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
full_name = str(input('Enter  your full name: '))
full_name = full_name.upper()

sum = 0
for i in full_name:
    if ('A' in i) or ('J' in i) or ('S' in i):
        sum += 1
    if ('B' in i) or ('K' in i) or ('T' in i):
        sum += 2
    if ('C' in i) or ('L' in i) or ('U' in i):
        sum +=3
    if ('D' in i) or ('M' in i) or ('V' in i):
        sum +=4
    if ('E' in i) or ('N' in i) or ('W' in i):
        sum+=5
    if ('F' in i) or ('O' in i) or ('X' in i):
        sum+=6
    if ('G' in i) or ('P' in i) or ('Y' in i):
        sum+=7
    if ('H' in i) or ('Q' in i) or ('Z' in i):
        sum+=8
    if ('I' in i) or ('R' in i):
        sum+=9
print(sum)
```

A couple mistakes you made:

.upper does return to string to in upper case, but you need to save it somewhere for later use.

You didn't want to nest the ifs, you didn't want to add 5 to a if it contained A, B, C, D, and E.

For i in full_name, iterates thru full_name, and you can use i, as each char in full_name.

X in 'Y', returns true if X is in Y, so just use logic operators with them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so let's think for a second what you're actually doing so you understand why it is failing:

First of all, the first part should be

```
full_name = full_name.upper()
```

So the variable is modified and stored

Then, while inside the for loop you're asking

```
if 'A' or 'J' or 'S' in full_name
```

Because `'A'` will be in `full_name`,`sum` will be increased by the value you chose.
Then, without going to the next step of the loop you're asking

```
if 'B' or 'K' or 'T' in full_name:
```

Because `'B'` will be in `full_name`, `sum` will be increased by the value you chose.

You're actually not using your `i` variable at all, you're asking again if `'foo'` is in `full_name` and it will always be like that (in the example you give), *then* it goes to the second step and does it again and so on.

What you want to do is use your `i` variable so you can evaluate step by step, and when it does fulfill your condition, go to the next step of the iteration.

What you're trying to do should look something more like this:

```
full_name = full_name.upper()

sum = 0
for i in full_name:
    if i == 'A' or i == 'J' or i == 'S':
        sum += 1
    elif i == 'B' or i == 'K' or i == 'T':
        sum += 2
    elif i == 'C' or i == 'L' or i == 'U':
        sum +=3
    elif i == 'D' or i == 'M' or i == 'V':
        sum +=4
    elif i == 'E' or i == 'N' or i == 'W':
        sum+=5
    elif i == 'F' or i == 'O' or i == 'X':
        sum+=6
    elif i == 'G' or i == 'P' or i == 'Y':
        sum+=7
    elif i == 'H' or i == 'Q' or i == 'Z':
        sum+=8
    else i == 'I' or i == 'R':
        sum+=9

print(sum)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You explanation about `if` closures is not completely correct. ‘`if ‘A’ or whatever in whatever`’ will be always evaluated to `True` because `’A’` is `True`.

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong, but that's what I meant by > you're asking again if 'foo' is in full_name and it will always be like that (in the example you give)

Comment: Try to evaluate this in console: `’A’ or ‘B’ in ‘C’`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `if` statements I would use this structure:

```
full_name = full_name.upper()

sum = 0
for i in full_name:
    if i in 'AJS':
        sum += 1
    elif i in 'BKT':
        sum += 2
...
```

Here is my solution. First you can find common letters between the name and the string `s` using intersection. Second you can use the function `itemgetter()` to get values from the dictionary and sum them up:

```
from itertools import count
from operator import itemgetter

s = 'AJSBKTCLUDMVENWFOXGPYHQZIR'

# create dict for lookups
c = (i for i in count(start=1) for _ in range(3))
d = {i: next(c) for i in s}
# {'A': 1, 'J': 1, 'S': 1, 'B': 2, 'K': 2, 'T': 2, 'C': 3, 'L': 3, 'U': 3, 'D': 4, 'M': 4, 'V': 4, 'E': 5, 'N': 5, 'W': 5, 'F': 6, 'O': 6, 'X': 6, 'G': 7, 'P': 7, 'Y': 7, 'H': 8, 'Q': 8, 'Z': 8, 'I': 9, 'R': 9}

def func(name):
    name = name.upper()
    intersec = set(name).intersection(s)
    return sum(itemgetter(*intersec)(d))

print(func('Mykola Zotko'))
# 33
```

This solution should be very fast.